# Cutting branch and stick it in pot?

Tags: trees, plant-health, tree-care, branches

I've asked several of these questions, but this is more specific of a tree in my parking lot. I would like to grow this Bougainvillea in a pot in my rooftop.

Here's the branch. Will the branch survive if I cut it and stick it in a pot? I don't want to try this unless I know it will survive.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just "sticking a branch in a pot" is unlikely to work, but it's not difficult to take cuttings properly and probably the only things you will need to buy are some fungicide and some sterile potting compost (both available from any garden center).

See [here](https://homeguides.sfgate.com/propagate-bouganvilleas-cuttings-22744.html) for instructions. Basically, you need to select the most suitable part of the parent plant to use, make sure it doesn't die from lack of water before it has grown its own roots, and keep it from getting infected by disease before it is growing strongly enough to resist pests and diseases on its own.

Comment: Thanks. Would I be able to take these cuttings from the branch in the picture? I just have access to that branch since the actual tree's in the neighbor's house.